# Bash extract part of the cron job

Tags: bash

I would like to extract the IP address that appears after `--host` param in the cron job -

```
34 15 * * * (cd /to/the/directory; ./my_program.pl  --param1  --host 198.181.111.222 --server 198.181.333.444 --version 1.0 --port 80 --user uid >> collect.log 2>&1)
```

Thing is the parameters can appear in random order in the cron. I tried using `cut` but that works only when the params are strictly in order.

I tried following some suggestions on SO -

```
str=$(crontab -l)
echo "${str}"
awk -F'--' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' <<< $str
```

But this splits `str` by `--` and prints all token on separate lines.

How can we store `198.181.111.222` in a variable `$ip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep!!!

```
$ crontab -l | grep -oE '\-\-[a-z]+ [0-9\.]+'
--host 198.181.111.222
--server 198.181.333.444
--version 1.0
--port 80

$ crontab -l | grep -oE '\-\-host [0-9\.]+'
--host 198.181.111.222

$ crontab -l | grep -oE '\-\-host [0-9\.]+' | awk '{print $2}'
198.181.111.222
```

Set `$ip`:

```bash
ip=$(crontab -l | grep -oE '\-\-host [0-9\.]+' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the fields of the line until you get to `--host`. Then print the next field.

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if ($i == "--host") {print $(i+1); break} }' <<< "$str"
```

Comment: Thanks, how can get the IP address in a variable though?

Comment: The same way you get any other output into a variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `sed`:

```
ip=$(crontab -l | sed -n 's/^.*[[:space:]]--host[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*\).*$/\1/p')
```

- This uses only [POSIX sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) features.
- It will fail if the `crontab -l` output contains two or more lines with `--host` in them.